# Can't click on text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I cannot seem to be able to move certain texts on illustrator when coloring a map with street names, I have to select a big area around the text to find an invisible box in order to move the font. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: how does your image look like when you view the outlines (cmd+Y)?

Answer (score 1):

I usually put the text on separate layers in illustrator, that way I can lock either the map objects or text as I need to. As for your problem, I have it sometimes too, but can't say what causes it. For me, it's usually copied and pasted objects from other files or InDesign, but not always.

If it irritates me too much, I move the text onto it's own layer, DUPLICATE that layer, Hide the TEXT layer, then outline all the text on the visible version. That way I can edit the text later if necessary, but I don't have to worry about selecting the text in a weird way.

It's not really an answer, but a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Long back it happened for me as well., I did the following method.

1. Select the particular text and go to Menu > Object > Expand
   or
2. select the text, go to Menu > Object > Rasterize

Sure any one of the statement may help,